# Converting 2 strings to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting 2 strings back from an API one for the date, and one for the time. I need to convert the 2 of them into a single DateTime object with the date and time in it. the 2 strings I get back are

```
Date: "2017-10-17" 
Time: "8:00PM"
```

Below is what I am trying to do and I can not get it to work. If I remove the time from it I can parse just the date, but I cant seem to figure out the pattern to add the time in it.

```
string date = "2017-10-17";
string time = "8:00PM"'

string startTime = $"{date} {time}";

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mmtt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

How can I get those 2 strings to combine into a single DateTime object?

Comment: Just guessing, but probably need to use format of "yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt" instead.

Comment: I HATE when its something so simple I just overlook! Works now, and not sure how I did not see that before asking a dumb question! :)

Comment: just `DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(date + " " + time)`

Comment: Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly. So use one d not dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string date = "2017-10-17";
string time = "8:00PM";

string startTime = $"{date} {time}";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime, "yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```